# dynamic modal (materialize.css) does't open with Vue,js

Tags: vue.js, materialize

I have a component in Vue.js, in which I create dynamic modals, but I can not open them, I think I'm doing everything right, because we call function and it responds with alert (), but it does not open the modal

```
<template>
<div  v-for="(index,noticia) in noticias">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
        <div id="modal-{{noticia.id}}" class="modal" v-if="noticia.videoValue == false">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <youtube :video-id.sync="videoId"></youtube>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Fechar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card horizontal">
            <!-- Mostra imaggem do lado direito -->
            <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light" v-if="pair(index)">
                <img class="responsive-img" @click.prevent.sync="openModal(noticia.id)"
                     :src="'storage/noticias/images/' + noticia.photo"
                     :class="{'activator': noticia.videoValue}"/>
            </div>

            <div class="card-stacked">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">{{ noticia.title }}<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span><br/>
                    <span class="card-date">{{ noticia.created_at.date | date-format }}</span>
                    <p>{{ noticia.description | substring 140}}</p>
                    <p><span v-for="tag in noticia.tags"><a href="#!" @click="searchByTag(tag.tag)">#{{ tag.tag }}</a> </span></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Mostra imaggem do lado esquerdo -->
            <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light" v-if="impar(index)">
                <img class="responsive-img" @click.prevent.sync="openModal(noticia.id)"
                     :src="'storage/noticias/images/' + noticia.photo"
                     :class="{'activator': noticia.videoValue}"/>
            </div>

            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">{{ noticia.title }}<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>{{ noticia.description }}</p>
                <p><span v-for="tag in noticia.tags"><a href="#!" @click="searchByTag(tag.tag)">#{{ tag.tag }}</a> </span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
</div>

<pagination v-if.sync="showPagination === true"
        :per-page="pagination.per_page"
        :current-page.sync="pagination.current_page"
        :total-records="pagination.total">
</pagination>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">


import PaginationComponent from './Pagination.vue';
import VueYouTubeEmbedComponent from 'vue-youtube-embed';
Vue.filter('substring', require('../filters/substring'));
Vue.filter('date-format', require('../filters/date-format'));
Vue.use(VueYouTubeEmbedComponent);
export default{
    components: {
        'pagination': PaginationComponent,
    },

    created(){
        this.getNoticias();
    },
    data(){
        return {
            noticias: [],
            week: "",
            loading: false,
            showPagination: false,
            currentTag: "",
            pagination: {
                current_page: 0,
                per_page: 0,
                total: 0,
            },
            videoId: "",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getNoticias(){
            this.showPagination = false;
            Vue.http.get('weekNoticias/' + this.week).then((response) => {

                let noticias = response.data.noticias.data;

                $.each(noticias, (index, value) => {
                    if (value.video != '') {
                        value.videoValue = false;
                    } else {
                        value.videoValue = true;
                    }
                });

                this.noticias = noticias;
                this.week = response.data.week;
            });
        },
        searchByTag(tag){
            this.currentTag = tag;
            this.showPagination = true;
            Vue.http.get('searchByTag/' + tag).then((response) => {
                let noticias = response.data.data;
                ;

                $.each(noticias, (index, value) => {
                    if (value.video != '') {
                        value.videoValue = false;
                    } else {
                        value.videoValue = true;
                    }
                });
                this.noticias = noticias;
                this.pagination.current_page = response.data.current_page - 1;
                this.pagination.per_page = response.data.per_page;
                this.pagination.total = response.data.total;
            });
        },
        searchByTagPagination(tag){
            this.showPagination = true; // para mostrar a paginação
            Vue.http.get('searchByTag/' + tag + '?page=' + this.pagination.current_page).then((response) => {
                this.noticias = response.data.data;
                this.pagination.current_page = response.data.current_page - 1;
                this.pagination.per_page = response.data.per_page;
                this.pagination.total = response.data.total;
            });
        },
        pair(index){
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        impar(index){
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        openModal(id){
            alert();
            $(`#modal-video-id`).modal('open');

        },
        getVideoId(url){
            this.videoId = this.$youtube.getIdFromURL(url);
        }

    },
    events: {
        'pagination::changed'(page){
            this.searchByTagPagination(this.currentTag);
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a no go:

```
<div id="modal-{{noticia.id}}"...
```

you can't use mustache-like sintax in the attributes, it will only work inside divs: {{noticia.id}}. I suggest use vue for everything or jquery for everything, mixing this things up its complex.

if the modal has css to be shown all the time, this will work

in html:

```
<div class="modal" v-if="noticia.showModal === true">
```

in javascript:

```
openModal(id){
        this.noticias[id].showModal = true;
    },
```